# javafx rendering in scaled canvas

Tags: canvas, rendering, javafx-8

I'm having a javaFX 8 canvas, which is scalable on scroll, so the `setScaleX` and `setScaleY` methods will be called with the new value.

I'm wondering if there is a rendering method to have a sharp rendering (like a vector graphic) if the canvas is scaled.

Answer (score 1):

it seems like its not possible on a canvas, as we have here a pixelbased rendering.
my solution is to replace the canvas with a pane and just use the geometric shapes provided by javaFX